# why can't I see my code environment in puppet enterprise

Tags: puppet-enterprise

I am new to puppet enterprise.  I have installed puppet enterprise in my server.  the lower left corner of my console page says v2023.20.

I have not created a node group yet.  my understanding is, I can deploy the code environment to individual node..

I think puppet enterprise is connected to my bitbucket, because I am able to see the repo branches when I run puppet-code deploy --all.

when I click on nodes -> run puppet, and "select an environment for nodes to run in", shouldn't I be able to see my code environment? the only environment I see in the console is "production", can someone shed some light?

I do see my other environments in my code-staging/environments directory, but only see "production" in code/environments directory, why?

```
[root@pe environments]# puppet-code deploy --all
Deploying all environments.
Found 0 environments.
Found 3 environments.
[
  {
    "environment": "master",
    "id": 12,
    "status": "queued"
  },
  {
    "environment": "production",
    "id": 13,
    "status": "queued"
  },
  {
    "environment": "webapp",
    "id": 14,
    "status": "queued"
  }
]
[root@pe environments]#
```